# minicom US Robotics 33.6 Sportster Debian Linux

Tags: linux, modem

I am trying to get a US Robotics Sportster 33.6 modem external working in minicom.  When I fire up minicom it will initialize the modem and the lights will fire up, but it will not let me send any commands to the modem within minicom.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?
Also, no errors are showing up.  I am trying to connect to ttyS0 with 57600 baud rate 8N1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type  `ATZ`  (even if the display shows nothing) and then press Enter.

Try to lower the speed and alwayst test with ATZ and Enter.